# Store products management

Tags: oop, dart, architecture

I’m creating an app for managing a store. I need to manage the following data relating to each product: the name, the purchase cost and the sales prices (which depend on which retailer is selling the product). In the following image I have represented in the table the data that I need to save and manage.

[image]

I know that over time, those who use the app will need to enter new products and new ‘price groups’ (the ‘Selling Price …’ columns of the table).

I’m using an object oriented language ([Dart](https://dart.dev/)). What could be the best way to organize the code? What classes should I create?

If you need more details, please let me know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need just one class `Product`:

```dart
class Product {
  final String name;
  final double cost; // Or int
  final List<int> sellingPrice;

  const Product(this.name, this.cost, this.sellingPrice);
}
```

Then you can [get](https://api.dart.cn/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Iterable/elementAt.html) and [add](https://api.dart.cn/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/List/add.html) selling prices to the list inside the object.

This assumes that the selling price is just a number. If, for example, you want to keep track also of the timestamp of the selling price then you would need another class:

```dart
class SellingPrice {
  final double price;
  final DateTime timestamp;

  const SellingPrice(this.price, this.timestamp);
}

class Product {
  final String name;
  final double cost; // Or int
  final List<SellingPrice> sellingPrice;

  const Product(this.name, this.cost, this.sellingPrice);
}
```

A lot depends on how you plan to interact with the object. There could be more efficient structures or different organizations (for example not using a [`List`](https://api.dart.cn/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/List-class.html) but a [`Set`](https://api.dart.cn/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Set-class.html)).

Comment: thank you very much for your response! The problem I would have using a `List` is that I wouldn’t have an identifier (and mnemonic help) to the sales price columns. I could use a `Map<String, double>` but, so, how can I make sure that all products are assigned the price corresponding to each ‘Selling Price …’ column?